# Django Deployed Admin Account - Missing Table

Tags: sql, django, cloud, admin

My local Django app has an admin account, which I can successfully login to. However, when I deploy this app to the Google's Cloud by following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#download_app); I get the photographed error. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you migrate your app with `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes, as part of setting up the app locally, I used that command without error. The app was then fully functional in my local env. The app also displayed the root page and the login page when deployed, however when I entered the login credentials the error appeared

Comment: You haven't setup databases in your remote servers. In fact it should be setup by running a simple *python manage.py migrate* in the remote. If this didn't help, you can use mysql shell to check if the table exists in the database or not.

Comment: Thanks @SpiXel that sounds like the root of the issue. However, my remote server is the Google Cloud Engine, which does include a cloud sql db, but I don't know how to run shell commands in that environment?